# how to dissmiss keyboard in uisearchbar?

Tags: search, ios4, keyboard, uisearchbar, dismiss

I am working a navigation based application. In my application user can search using the UISearchBar. Now I want the keyboard to be dismissed after the user hits search (or done not sure which one it is). I tried doing the way it is done for UITextField but didn't work. so any help would be appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: Hi, please edit your question.  It doesn't make much sense.  Also a search for "keyboard UISearchBar dismiss" turns up tons of results.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps for anyone that else was looking for this.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [sbSearch resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Using `UISearchBarDelegate`.